# jQuery form narrow down an array input selection

Tags: jquery

I currently have a form which has dynamically generated array inputs. What I want to do is get the inputs of a certain array index and continue with some tasks I have to perform (validation and etc).

Now, I know I can select the inputs like this:

```
var id = $('#hiddenInputContainer').find('[name="item[1][id]"]')
var name = $('#hiddenInputContainer').find('[name="item[1][name]"]');
// so on...
```

But I'm thinking if it's possible to narrow the search of inputs to `[name^='item[1]']` and then find the `id` and `name`.

In my case the `hiddenInputContainer` will have a lot of inputs and I want to optimize the javascript as much as possible. So how would I narrow down the list?

P.S. I've tried doing `var inputs = $('#hiddenInputContainer').find('[name="item[1]"]')` and afterwards `inputs.find('[name*="id"]')`, but that doesn't work for some reason?

Example of how the html looks:

```
<div id="hiddenInputContainer">
    <input type="hidden" name="item[1][id]" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item[1][name]" value="a name for item 1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item[2][id]" value="2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item[2][name]" value="a name for item 2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item[3][id]" value="51"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item[3][name]" value="a name for item 51"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this -

```
var inputs = $('#hiddenInputContainer').find('[name^="item[1]"]');
inputs.filter('[name*="id"]')
```